# Traverse a nested Object and modify a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I have a nested Object as follows:

All I wanted is a recursive function that traverses through this object and assigns a random value to the 'id' attribute.

```
 let data = [{ id: 1, name: '', children: [{ id: 11, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 12, name: '', children: [{ id: 121, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 122, name: '', children: [] }] } ] }, { id: 2, name: '', children: [{ id: 21, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 22, name: '', children: [{ id: 221, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 222, name: '', children: [] }] } ] } ];
```

Here is code I tried and I got it fixed

```
const cloneNodesWithNewIds = (tree) => {
  const result = tree.map((elem) =>
    elem.children ? {
      ...elem,
      id: Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1),
      children: cloneNodesWithNewIds(elem.children),
    } :
    elem
  );
  return result;
}

console.log(cloneNodesWithNewIds(data))
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is faster

```js
let data = [{ id: 1, name: '', children: [{ id: 11, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 12, name: '', children: [{ id: 121, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 122, name: '', children: [] }] } ] }, { id: 2, name: '', children: [{ id: 21, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 22, name: '', children: [{ id: 221, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 222, name: '', children: [] }] } ] } ];

const maxVal = 300;
let rndArr = []
const getRdn = () => { let rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random()*maxVal); while (rndArr.includes(rnd)) rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random()*maxVal); rndArr.push(rnd); return rnd; }; // unique. Can be simplified if not needed

data = JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify(data)
    .replace(/"id":\d+/g, match => `"id":${getRdn()}`)
)
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do what you want

```js
let data = [{ id: 1, name: '', children: [{ id: 11, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 12, name: '', children: [{ id: 121, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 122, name: '', children: [] }] } ] }, { id: 2, name: '', children: [{ id: 21, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 22, name: '', children: [{ id: 221, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 222, name: '', children: [] }] } ] } ];

function recursiveEdition(object, label, value) {
    // If we the object is not an object, there is nothing to do
    if (typeof object !== 'object') {
      return;
    }

    // We check every attribute of the object
    Object.keys(object).forEach((index) => {
        if (index === label) {
            // If it is the desired index, we change the value
            object[index] = value;
        } else {
            if it is not the desired index, we continue the navigation
            recursiveEdition(object[index], label, value);
        } 
    });

    return object
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Here is recursive approach. If obj is type array then call on `forEach`

```js
const random = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)

const updateAttr = (item) => {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    item.forEach(updateAttr);
  } else {
    item.id = random();
    updateAttr(item.children); 
  }
}  

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "",
    children: [
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "",
        children: [],
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        name: "",
        children: [
          {
            id: 121,
            name: "",
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: 122,
            name: "",
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "",
    children: [
      {
        id: 21,
        name: "",
        children: [],
      },
      {
        id: 22,
        name: "",
        children: [
          {
            id: 221,
            name: "",
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: 222,
            name: "",
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

updateAttr(data);

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative version using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It relatively clean, however it does introduce a dependency, so there is a trade-off.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = [{ id: 1, name: '', children: [{ id: 11, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 12, name: '', children: [{ id: 121, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 122, name: '', children: [] }] }] }, { id: 2, name: '', children: [{ id: 21, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 22, name: '', children: [{ id: 221, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 222, name: '', children: [] }] }] }];
const myPRNG = (value) => Math.abs(Math.floor(Math.sin(value) * 1000));

const modify = (data, rng) => objectScan(['**.id'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ parent, property, value }) => {
    parent[property] = rng(value);
  }
})(data);

console.log(modify(myData, myPRNG));
// => 10

console.log(myData);
// => [ { id: 841, name: '', children: [ { id: 1000, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 537, name: '', children: [ { id: 998, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 498, name: '', children: [] } ] } ] }, { id: 909, name: '', children: [ { id: 836, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 9, name: '', children: [ { id: 885, name: '', children: [] }, { id: 868, name: '', children: [] } ] } ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)